# VC++ Visual Studio added .hpp files in subdirectory but get "Error: cannot open source file ..."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++

This is driving me nuts - I've added a number of .hpp files in subdirectories in the root of an existing VC++ projects source directory.

Visual Studio complains "Error: cannot open source file ..." but if I right click on the  and select open document, VS can display it.

I've tried:

- "Rescan solution" which appears to do nothing.
- Adding existing item (both on it's own and with a "filter" - which appears to be a directory?)
- Closing the project and VStudio in the vain hope it would eventually discover the directories/files I'd added

VStudio complains it cannot find these files when it is capable of opening them?  My question is simply this:  "How can I add a directory containing source files to a VC++ project such that the linker/complier can see them?

(disclaimer; i've never used Visual Studio before or many Microsoft products, so am finding this all very alien)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround;

Add the files to a directory outside of the project and then reference those directories in the "Additional Include Directories" in Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General.

Why I can't add additional directories within the project and have Visual Studio rescan them (like an Eclipse refresh) is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to *include* any header file you'd like to use into your cpp files by `#include "path/file.hpp"`. in your case your probably didn't specify *path*, e.g. "subdir/file.hpp"

Comment: Thanks for swift reponse Andy, the includes were specified with reachable paths "path/file.hpp".  I now have a workaround, answered below

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answer at the following question. This answer fixed the problem for me. It has to do with adding $(ProjectDir) in the "C/C++ Include Directory" in the project settings.

["Cannot open include file" error in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955874/cannot-open-include-file-error-in-vs2010)

The answer linked above, fixed my issue with not being able to include subdirectory files inside of the project. I hope this helps anyone else having this issue.

Thanks,