# "Cannot open include file" error in VS2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, build, include

I'm trying to compile open source tool "abc".

When I tried to build the solution file, I got a lot of error messages.

[image]

The c source code has include directive, and VS2010 cannot find the header files. The file structure is as follows.

[image]

```
#include "src/misc/util/abc_global.h"
#include "pr.h"
```

In project property, I tried to add [$(SolutionDir)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(v=vs.71).aspx) and $(ProjectDir), but it didn't work.

What might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: To verify, the location of `aig.h` is `C:\users\sucho\Desktop\abc\src\aig\aig\aig.h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I needed to setup properties in C/C++/General/Additional Include Directories

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `$(ProjectDir)`. Perhaps your solution is one folder above the project.

Comment: I tried $(PorjectDir) and $(SolutionDIr), but neither seems to work.